# adb does not recognize my Nexus 7 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nexus-7, adb

I'm trying to test drive the Ubuntu touch on my Nexus 7 (2013) which recently has been upgraded to Lollipop (5.0.2). So I followed [the steps](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/) starting with backing up my device. But the problem is that `adb` does not list my device!

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached 

$
```

Also:

```
$ adb backup -apk -shared -all
adb: unable to connect for backup
```

It's in the case that my tablet is successfully recognized as a mass storage and I can copy to/from it easily. I've also made sure that the developer mode is activated on my device, as I tap on `Build number` it tells me:

```
No need, you are already a developer.
```

Yet `adb` can not find it. How can I find what's wrong with it?

**[UPDATE]**

I just realized that I've also got a smart phone! It's a Moto G with KitKat 4.4.4 on it. `adb` does not find that either!

Answer (score 4):

On your device switch from 'media device' to 'camera device'. And adb will recognize.

Comment: Tested on both devices with negative results.

Comment: Something to do with USB drivers, do devices appear on device manager? (Control panel) try reinstall drivers.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? It's Ubuntu and there's no Control Panel. How should I reinstall USB drivers? BTW, as I mentioned devices work as mass storage as they should!

Comment: Thx - your solution works :-)

Comment: For reference : to switch from 'media' to 'camera', on the device one should go to Settings/Storage/Menu/USB